# Positive function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove the following result:

Let $\mu$ be a Lebesgue measure. Suppose $f$ is a measurable positive application . Show that 
 $\mu\Big(\left\{x\in[0,1]: f>3\right\}\Big)$  is zero

Please help me do do so. Thanks

Comment: I think this has to do with the fact, that if for any value of x in this interval the function takes the value above 1, the limit ends up going to infinity and thus does not exist, which means that the function never goes above 1 in the provided interval for x.

Answer (score 0):

Call your set $A:=\{f>1\}$. Suppose for contradiction $\mu(A)>0$. Then there is some $p>0$ such that $A_p:=\{f>2^p\}$ has measure $\delta>0$ (this is because you can think of $A$ as the limit of sets $A_p$ as $p\downarrow 0$).

Then for all $n$,

\begin{align*}
2^{np} \delta \leq \int_\limits{A_p} f^n \; d\mu \leq \int_\limits{[0,1]} f^n \; d\mu
\end{align*}

and letting $n\rightarrow \infty$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: what about the other implication is it true that $\mu\Big(\left\{x\in[0,1]: f(x)>1\right\}\Big)=0\;$ then $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]}f^n(x)d\mu(x)$$ exists ? if so how that?

Comment: Yes @aymen that would follow from the monotone convergence theorem. The sequence $f^n \rightarrow 0$ in that case.

Comment: can you please detail this idea more in your previous answer? In fact i don't see why $f_n\to 0$. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since $f$ is nonnegative and $<1$, then every $f^n(x)$ is a sequence tending, monotonically to zero. So you can apply the monotone convergence theorem.

If you need more details, it would be more suited for a new post since this question is different from your original one.

Comment: I will be greatfull if you detail your idea, i posted the question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2972358/lebesgue-measure-and-measurable-non-negative-function

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Supose $\mu([f>1])>0$. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$ and  $A_k =\left\{x\in[0,1]: f(x)>1+1/k \right\}$. For all $k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$ we have
$$
\int_{[0,1]}f^n(x)d\mu(x)
\geq 
\int_{A_k}f^n(x)d\mu(x)
\geq \int_{A_k}(1+\frac{1}{2k})^n d\mu(x)
\geq (1+\frac{1}{2k})^n\mu(A_k)
$$
The Lesbesgue measure is generated by the finite and open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$. So being a well-behaved measure in the sense that $A_k\uparrow A$ then $\lim_{k\to \infty}\mu(A_k)=\mu(A)$. This means that if $\lim_{k\to\infty}A_k=[f>0]$ then there should be a value $k_0> 0$ such that $\mu(A_{k_0})>0$

Comment: in your answer where you use $\mu(A_{k_0}) $ to deduce the contradiction?

Comment: We have, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}-\{0\}$, what $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{[0,1]} f^n(x)d\mu(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2k})^n\mu(A_k)=\infty$.  The convergence of limit $\lim_{k\to\infty} \mu(A_k)=\mu([f>1])$ is a uniform convergence. Then $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{2k})^n\mu(A_k)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2k})^n\mu(A_k)$.